# How to filter in typesensne collection of objects in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, typesense

I have item collections and in every item have item_prices collections of objects. Just need filter in item_prices and retrieve item_prices which matching with my parameters. Im sending parameters like this

```
filter_by = item_prices.priceline_id:=2 && 
            item_prices.company_id:=3
```

but it retrieves matched and nonmatched item_prices. How can I filter this correctly?
[image]

For example now my collection is like this

```
{
            "document": {
                "Brands": "SCHULTHEISS",
                "Categories": [],
                "id": "1398702",
                "item_prices": [
                    {
                        "company_id": "3",
                        "priceline_id": "0",
                    },
                    {
                        "company_id": "3",
                        "priceline_id": "1",
                    },
                    {
                        "company_id": "3",
                        "priceline_id": "2",
                    },
                    {
                        "company_id": "3",
                        "priceline_id": "3",
                    },
}
```

but when im filtering `item_prices.priceline_id:=2 && item_prices.company_id:=3`

result must be like this

```
    {
            "document": {
                "Brands": "SCHULTHEISS",
                "Categories": [],
                "id": "1398702",
                "item_prices": [
                    {
                        "company_id": "3",
                        "priceline_id": "2",
                    }
}
```

Comment: Show us what your item collection looks like. Provided data insufficient.  *but it retrieves matched and nonmatched item_stocks.* no idea how `item_stocks` comes from

Comment: I updated my question. there is my item_prices collection.

Comment: Post as a text and add what you need as output

Comment: For example i have this collection.
"document": {
  "Brands": "Pik-Nik KIDS",
  "Categories": ["HALAL"],
  "id": "1398218",
  "item_prices": [
  {
  "company_id": "2",
  "priceline_id": "1",
  },
  {
  "company_id": "2",
  "priceline_id": "2",
  },
}

parameters: filter_by = item_prices.priceline_id:=1 && 
            item_prices.company_id:=2
and waiting output.

"document": {
  "Brands": "Pik-Nik KIDS",
  "Categories": ["HALAL"],
  "id": "1398218",
  "item_prices": [
  {
  "company_id": "2",
  "priceline_id": "1",
 },
}

Answer (score 0):

Typesense will return full documents that have matches, hence the returned document will have all your `item_prices` and you will have to filter the `item_prices` yourself.

The only thing that Typesense guarantees, is that the document **has** some `item_prices` matching your filter